# "Whose difficulty is in-between"

Tags: word-choice

> This doctoral thesis is very technical and therefore hard to read. On the other hand,
>   this book on the subject is a bit too naive. Our goal is to give a
>   text whose difficulty is in-between.

I think that the last sentence above is incorrect. How could one phrase that the text is more precise and detailed than the book, but still less detailed than the thesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample sentence isn't incorrect.  It is stilted (“give a text” is not modern usage; “write a text” or “produce a text”, etc. would be more modern) and slightly informal.  You could replace *[in-between](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-between)* with *[intermediate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intermediate#Adjective)*, which means “Being between two extremes, or in the middle of a range”.

Comment: I'd go with "It has been our goal to produce a text intermediate in difficulty."